# Question on Cauchy's argument principle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $C$ be a simple closed contour and $f$ is analytic on and inside $C$ with no zeros or poles on $C$. Then if $Z$ are the number of zeros and $P$ are the number of poles inside $C$ then by Argument principle $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=Z-P$$
**Question**: Prove that $$\Im\left(\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)=Z-P$$

I tried using $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=i(Z-P)$$ Now taking the imaginary parts since $Z-P$ is real we get $$\Im\left(\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)=Z-P$$

But then we always have  $$\Re\left(\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)=0?$$

Comment: That is all correct. What is the problem?

Comment: @MartinR Then the real part of the integral is 0 always? How?

Comment: As you observed: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ is equal to $i(Z-P)$, and that is a purely imaginary number.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that the real part is given by the variation of $\log |f|$ and that is always a single valued function as opposed to the imaginary part which is the multivalued argument; that's why on a loop, the real part of the integral vanishes

Comment: @Conrad Thanks a lot for the beautiful explaination.

Comment: Happy to be of help

Comment: @Conrad Can you please write as an answer. I will accept it happily